# Кириллица в markdown ссылках

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, кириллица

Markdown не верно парсит ссылки, содержащие кириллицу:

- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Абсцисса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)
- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ордината](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)
- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Кроме того, чтобы ввести такую ссылку, она должна быть экранирована:

```
Программирование -> %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0...
```

Причем для любых видов обозначения ссылок ([см. справку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)).

Проблема также наблюдается и в комментариях (markdown в комментариях не используется), например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412892/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5#comment412893_412892).

Comment: А на ХК разве не так было? Я всегда экранированно ссылки постил

Answer (score 5):

Это, конечно, баг, и его необходимо исправлять, но для новых сообщений существует очевидный обходной путь:

[Программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
[Программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```
[Программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
[Программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Программирование)
```

Comment: Да, я про это уже написал: 
"Кроме того, чтобы ввести такую ссылку, она должна быть экранирована:
Программирование -> %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0...  ".

Comment: Кстати, а полностью доменное имя на русском как выглядеть будет? Проверяем: [ПЕРВАЯ](http://президент.рф/) - как вбиваю в строку поиска (http://президент.рф/), [ВТОРАЯ](http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/) - как копирую из нее (http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/)