# Когда начнут учитываться особенности русского языка?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нытьё

1. Неправильно работает вставка гиперссылок при помощи html, если в ссылке используются русские буквы.

   Например в вопросе «[Из каких функциональных блоков состоит Desktop Environment?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424049/181472)» ссылка на википедию у меня выглядит некорректно (русские буквы не входят в подчеркнутую часть)

   UPD: было - [Кириллица в markdown ссылках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-markdown-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85?rq=1)
2. "Как сделать" = "how to", не надо, наверное, при выводе похожих вопросов в правой колонке, учитывать слова "как сделать", как влияющие на похожесть.
3. Морфология, склонения - вот это всё, оно учитывается при поиске, связывании, тегах и везде? А будет?

   Вопросы могут содержать одни и те же слова в разных падежах. Нужно чтобы слова точно совпадали, или словоизменение учитывается?

Comment: Пожалуйста, распишите более подробное второй и третий пункт.

Answer (score 1):

Первый пункт был исправлен какое-то время назад. Остальные упомянутые вами вещи должны работать «из коробки». Для того, чтобы дать более развернутый ответ на второй и третий вопросы, мне необходимы конкретные примеры неверного поведения.

Comment: У вопроса [Как сделать прозрачность jPanel](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461744) в похожих есть [Как сделать луч радара?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452348). Кроме «Как сделать» у вопросов нет ничего похожего. Нужно не учитывать общие фразы при поиске похожих вопросов.