# В комментариях некорректно парсятся ссылки на ответ с неэкранированной кириллицей

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, комментарии, кириллица

Сразу скажу, что проблема всплывала, но она, отмечена, как решенная:
[Кириллица в markdown ссылках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-markdown-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

**Суть проблемы:**
Ссылки на ответ, содержащие кириллицу, обрабатываются некорректно.
Возьмем такую ссылку на ответ:

`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/Смена-цвета-при-нажатии/553585#553585`.

На Мете в сообщении она преобразуется корректно: [Смена цвета при нажатии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553585#553585), а вот в комментарии нет.

Обратите внимание на последний комментарий на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте видно, что еще и слеш куда-то пропал, между ID ответа и ЧПУ.

---

Уточню, что я не спрашиваю о том, как мне добавить ссылку на ответ, чтобы парсер ее "прожевал", это мне известно, я указываю на дефект в обработке одного из вариантов ссылки на ответ.

---

Добавил вариант, демонстрирующий воспроизведение не только на Yandex Browser, но и в Opera. Из гифки ниже видно, откуда берется ссылка и что в ней нет спецсимволов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Обновление

**искусственная разбивка комментария длиннее 100 символов**:

[Ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3545/13336):

> В указаной вами ссылке содержатся запрещенные символы `&zwnj;` и
>   `&#8203`. Скорее всего, кто–то портит вам буфер обмена. [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky)

[Комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5#comment11376_3545):

> Эти спецсимволы (невидимые разделители) вставляет движок SO (уж не
>   знаю, на сервере или на клиенте), чтобы текст комментариев не вылезал
>   за правую границу. Попробуйте в комментарии написать 100 букв без
>   пробелов, увидите, как эти символы магически добавятся. [@Roman](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/183980/roman)

Comment: Пример этой же ссылки в комментарии: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/Смена-цвета-при-нажатии/553585#553585

Comment: Ссылки на ответ вроде выглядят по другому...если нажмете на кнопку "поделиться" и увидите ссылку, там даже кириллицы не будет... только ссылка вида http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553585/191482  ......... а не парсятся скорее из-за решетки..... только решетки то и нет в ссылках на ответы...... это более похоже ссылка на комментарий)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, эти ссылки из профиля из недавней активности.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553585#553585

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, экранированные ссылки парсятся корректно. Я специально в заголовке упомянул неэкранированные.

Comment: При вставке комментария я его не экранировал. Я взял исходный вариант из адресной строки `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553590#553590`.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в том же Yandex Browser (и не только), при копировании ссылок с кириллицей они не экранируются перед передачей в буфер обмена.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Комментарии обрабатывались хитрым регулярным выражением, которое учитывало не все символы. Внесли изменения в регулярное выражение. Если ошибка проявится на других данных, пожалуйста, дайте знать.

Comment: Не согласен. Ссылка должна автоматически экранироваться, если еще не была экранирована перед вставкой в комментарий.

Comment: К слову, символы я никакие не добавлял. Ссылка скопирована была из адресной строки браузера после перехода из профиля пользователя. Я пробовал скопировать ее как текст и из профиля - тот же результат. Если символы и добавляются, то на стороне сервера, как я полагаю.

Comment: @VenZell На сколько я понял из разговора с ответственным разработчиком, серверу уже строка, в которой содержатся не поддерживаемые парсером символы. Ребята говорят, что проблема именно в том, что вставляет в поле ввода из буфера обмена.

Comment: Попробуйте сами скопировать этот адрес неэкранированный (из примера в тексте вопроса) и вставить его в комментарий. В примере точно никаких спецсимволов нет. Если дело в спецсимволах окажется, значит, косяк на моей стороне, действительно.

Comment: @VenZell Вставленная вами ссылка действительно не работает (так как в ней парсер находит спец. символы). Но если я перехожу в вопрос и копирую точно такую же ссылку из адресной строки, то она работает.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, гифку. Там неоткуда взяться спецсимволам. Я хочу докопаться до истины, и только поэтому настаиваю на проверке вопроса.

Comment: @VenZell Попробовал воспроизвести в Google Chrome и Yandex Browser. В хроме все работает, а вот в сборке Яндекса – нет.

Comment: Потому что Chrome экранирует ссылку по умолчанию, а Yandex Browser нет. Opera тоже НЕ экранирует и в ней копирование не работает (см. гифку в вопросе).

Еще раз повторяюсь, если ссылка кодирована (URLencoded), то все ок при вставке в комментарий. Если нет - она не парсится. Так вот на мой взгляд это проблема серверная, а не браузера или пользователя. Я даже уже и не знаю, как конкретнее на проблему указать, что некодированные ссылки не парсятся. Они должны кодироваться на стороне сервера, а не клиента.

Comment: Эти спецсимволы (невидимые разделители) вставляет движок SO (уж не знаю, на сервере или на клиенте), чтобы текст комментариев не вылезал за правую границу. Попробуйте в комментарии написать 100 букв без пробелов, увидите, как эти символы магически добавятся.

Comment: @VenZell Кажется, у нас есть возможность домучить дефект! Теперь я понял проблему, спасибо! Пообщался с ребятами. Сейчас комментарии обрабатываются хитрым регулярным выражением, которое учитывает не все символы. Oded внес исправление в логику регулярного выражение. Как только оно пройдет ревью, можно будет проверить работу.

Comment: Рад это слышать, спасибо

Comment: @Roman, за пояснение вам отдельное спасибо. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @VenZell Пожалуйста, проверьте, все ли исправлено.

Comment: Все исправлено, спасибо

Comment: @VenZell Вам спасибо за отзыв! (И Oded за исправление дефекта!)

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, в комментариях не поддерживается:

- оборачивание голой ссылки в название вопроса (похоже на [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be))
- распознавание кириллических ЧПУ (а вот это скорее [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82))

До тех пор, пока это не починят (если вообще починят), в комментарии можно явным образом публиковать ссылку в Markdown:

- Исходник: `[Смена цвета при нажатии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553585#553585)`
- Результат: [Смена цвета при нажатии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553585#553585),

Как ее можно получить:

1. Плагины к браузеру, позволяющие копировать ссылку как что угодно. У меня на Firefox стоит [CoLT](https://www.borngeek.com/firefox/colt/), но наверняка вариантов много.
2. Юзерскрипт [SE Comment Link Helper](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper) заменяет ссылки сам.

Comment: [Смена цвета при нажатии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553579/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/553585#553585)

Comment: Мне не нужно оборачивание ссылки в название вопроса. Сама ссылка не размечается как ссылка. И обратите внимание, пожалуйста, на отсутствующий слеш. Я отдельно указал на то, что в сообщении ссылка распознается, а в комментарии нет. Как именно распознается, в принципе, до лампочки. Главное, что сейчас по ней перейти нельзя в комментарии.

Comment: @VenZell вроде можно перейти, просто она ведет на вопрос, а не на ответ.

Comment: Главное, что на ответ перейти нельзя, то есть поведение в любом случае некорректное. Об обходных способах я знаю, вроде "Поделиться" ссылкой на ответ и использовать ее, или вставить экранированную ссылку, или в формате markdown.

Comment: @VenZell короткая ссылка на ответ должна сработать.

Comment: Я и говорю, что она работает и что это альтернативный вариант. Проблема в том, что указанные мной ссылки не работают.

Comment: @VenZell значит я неправильно понял ваш вопрос. )

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, что сообщение может быть понято двояко и обновил его.

Comment: @VenZell симметрично обновил ответ )